# Continous x-axis background-image slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, slide

I have a div element with a big image background css rule.

Now I would like to slide the image in x-axis smoothly, is there any lightweight plugin or snippet?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Not clear at all... Do you simply want to repeat the same image horizontally?

Comment: nope i would like to make it slides in background in left direction, it just repeating cause of css rule background-repeat:repeat-x; i just need to make it move continuosly on left direction and x-axes

Comment: Like this? http://jsbin.com/uzifag/1/

Comment: yep, but i can't see it moving.. strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the style for webkit: http://jsbin.com/uzifag/2/

Note that I'm moving the background-position to negative width of the image. If you want it to be the opposite direction, positive width will work. You can play with the duration of the animation as suits your needs.

```
body{
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/1920/1080/) repeat-x center left;
  -webkit-animation: slidex 20s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: slidex 20s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: slidex 20s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: slidex 20s linear infinite;
          animation: slidex 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidex
{
  FROM{background-position:0 center;}
  TO{background-position:-1920px center;}
}
@-moz-keyframes slidex
{
  FROM{background-position:0 center;}
  TO{background-position:-1920px center;}
}
@-ms-keyframes slidex
{
  FROM{background-position:0 center;}
  TO{background-position:-1920px center;}
}
@-o-keyframes slidex
{
  FROM{background-position:0 center;}
  TO{background-position:-1920px center;}
}
@keyframes slidex
{
  FROM{background-position:0 center;}
  TO{background-position:-1920px center;}
}
```

Comment: i'm on FF it doesn't move :P

Comment: You'll need to add the keyframes and animation definitions for each vendor: -moz-, -ms-, -o-, -webkit-

Comment: do you see that moving on left? i can't see that working strange :/ think it's my problem

Comment: ahh ok, please add full browser support (moz,o,ms) in your css3 so i can put this as checked ;)

Comment: Only IE10 supports CSS3 animations, I believe. Safari should be working though.

Comment: Fantastic answer dude, Plus'd + Favourited.